# 2d and 3d arrays in objective-c...HELP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Im new to objective-c programming and im currently working on an iPhone project and my task has to deal with 2d and 3d arrays, I have actually been trying for a while but im not sure if im on the right track. Im trying to achieve the following:

1)Trip 1 must be in index 0 of array1
2)Trip 1 has departure time, arrival time and trip instructions
3)now im trying to have the departure in array2 index 0 that's being pointed to by trip1 in array1 in index zero, and arrival in array2 index 1
4)array2 will have array3 that has instructions for trip one

I have for loops and everything is working perfectly i just need to know how to do the above, in other words how to save these information in the manner i have described in the  above steps?

i have done this but not sure if im right or wrong:
Array1 = [[NSmutableArray] init];
Array2 = [[NSmutableArray] inti];
[Array1 insertObject:Array2 atIndex:0];

[Array1 addObject:ObjectToAdd, i]
[Array2 addObject:ObjectToAdd, i]

Note: "i" starts from zero

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025861/multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSMutableArray and insert different objects into it.
For example you have 3 classes say A, B, C

```
NSMutableArray mainArray = [NSMutable array];
A array1 = [A new];
B array2 = [B new];
C array3 = [C new];

[mainArray addObject:array1];
[mainArray addObject:array2];
[mainArray addObject:array3];
```

Now you can access these objects via your `mainArray`.

Comment: The problem is i cant pre-determine how many objects i need before i get into my loop because my loop determines the number of trips i have. So, all my arrays must be dynamic.

Comment: Ofcourse you can add as many elements you want to the mutable array.